# MS Azure Machine Learning - Notebook extremely slow in comparison to GC

Tags: azure, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I work with a jupyter notebook on different platforms.

The notebook includes a detectron2 algorithm.

The runtime for the training process on different platforms differs significantl (Same Code, Same parameters, same data)

**Google Colab**

- K80 GPU (Successfully used while training)
- Data stored on Google Drive
- Torch: 1.9.0+cu111
- **Runtime: 4,5h**

---

**Microsoft Azure - Machine Learning**

- K80 GPU (Successfully used while training)
- STANDARD_NC6
- Data stored an Azure Files
- Torch: 1.9.0+cu111
- **Runtime: 15h**

Why is the expensive Azure ML three times slower than free Google Colab and is there a possibility to improve that?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am also experiencing very slow training on Azure ML.

Comment: I asked MS for a more performant gpu, but this seems to be a problem in my region. So i do not followed this anymore and work with gc/local gpu.